# Min max query for temperatures on a day

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry new to MYSQL, so not quite sure on the syntax and having trouble.

Trying to find the maximum and minimum temperatures for the current day in a certain location.

For example.
After the min and max (message) temperature for today (timeof) from the outside1 lcoation (locationmap)

table setup; (screenshot)

[image]

```
mqtt / temperatures
-id
-timeof <- DATETIME field
-message <-- this is the temperature field
-topic
-qos
-hardwareid
-locationmap
```

Just running this query inside MySQL workbench atm...

```
SELECT @min_temp:=MIN(message),@max_temp:=MAX(message),`timeof` FROM `mqtt`.`temperatures`;
SELECT * FROM  `mqtt`.`temperatures` WHERE `timeof` >= CURDATE() AND (message=@min_temp OR message=@max_temp);
```

The above only returns a min/max but not for the current day and i think it is only returning the min.

Comment: "in a certain location" --- I don't see you're filtering your results by any location. Currently your queries are supposed to work with all locations

Comment: Not sure how to do it! the above query doesn't work that well.

Comment: so do it iteratively. The first step - select all temperatures from a required location.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause to group your results by location.

*eg*

```
SELECT locationmap, MIN(message) AS minTemp, MAX(message) AS maxTemp
   FROM temperatures
   GROUP BY locationmap;
```

That will give you a temperature range for each location.  Alternatively, you can restrict the results to a single location without grouping:

```
SELECT MIN(message) AS minTemp, MAX(message) AS maxTemp
   FROM temperatures
   WHERE locationmap='kitchen';
```

Comment: He only needs that from one `locationmap`

Comment: Where would you add the option of `timeof` >= CURDATE() ?

Comment: @Matt.: why do you need to add it?

Comment: I want to see the min/max temperatures for today in a certain location.

Comment: @Matt.: so what's the problem of adding another condition to `WHERE`?

Comment: as mentioned earlier, new to mysql queries, wasn't sorry how to do it.

Comment: @Matt you just combine all your filtering conditions with `AND` (if you want them all to apply).  You're already doing this in the query you supplied.

Comment: @Matt.: so how are you supposed to become "not new to mysql" when you haven't even learned the very basics? It's not learning, it's outsourcing your job (for free).